# when i use tincan library (tincan-0.3.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies-jarjar.jar) on android can't support for run android project

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, tin-can-api

when i run android project after using with tincan jar library version-(**tincan-0.3.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies-jarjar.jar**) can't not support for run android project into device.Please help me anyone how can **run and import** tincan library for supporting into android project?

```
I use eclipse android SDK ADT on window 7..
```

when android application Error show on console..

```
[2015-02-11 14:04:33 - MyTestPrj]   The library 'tincan-0.3.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies-jarjar.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
[2015-02-11 14:04:33 - MyTestPrj]   The following libraries were found:
[2015-02-11 14:04:33 - MyTestPrj]    - com/sun/jna/darwin/libjnidispatch.jnilib
[2015-02-11 14:04:33 - MyTestPrj]    - com/sun/jna/freebsd-amd64/libjnidispatch.so
[2015-02-11 14:04:33 - MyTestPrj]    - com/sun/jna/freebsd-i386/libjnidispatch.so

[2015-02-11 14:04:33 - MyTestPrj]  - com/sun/jna/linux-amd64/libjnidispatch.so
[2015-02-11 14:04:33 - MyTestPrj]    - com/sun/jna/linux-i386/libjnidispatch.so
[2015-02-11 14:04:33 - MyTestPrj]    - com/sun/jna/sunos-amd64/libjnidispatch.so
[2015-02-11 14:04:33 - MyTestPrj]    - com/sun/jna/sunos-sparc/libjnidispatch.so
[2015-02-11 14:04:33 - MyTestPrj]    - com/sun/jna/sunos-sparcv9/libjnidispatch.so
[2015-02-11 14:04:33 - MyTestPrj]    - com/sun/jna/sunos-x86/libjnidispatch.so
```

Comment: Note that this is a pretty old release and the current version 0.6.0 has a completely rewritten RemoteLRS interface that you'll want to upgrade to. I would suggest trying the 0.6.0 release and then reporting if you have the same issue. The name of the package is also kind of odd, "-jarjar.jar".

Comment: Mr,Brian J. Miller .How i can download this library for tincan 0.6.0 version. you can share to me link?

Comment: Releases can be found on the GitHub page https://github.com/RusticiSoftware/TinCanJava/releases see "Downloads" for a given release.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm learn simple tincan android project from this [ link https://github.com/RusticiSoftware/TinCanAndroid-Offline] and another [ link https://rusticisoftware.github.io/TinCanJava/ ] but not so okay for android tincan tutorial test. you can share me simple code for android tincan project. Mr.Brian J. Miller.